# How to assign resource dictionary for custom controls in a dll

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, resourcedictionary

I have a WPF custom control `MyControl.cs` in my application project (.exe) with its style in a resource dictionary in `MyControlResources.xaml`. This xaml is specified in `app.xaml` as a part of the merged dictionaries. Everything works fine.

Now I want to move this custom control into an existing DLL project that the application references. Is there a way that I can create the resource dictionary "assignment" in the DLL and make it transparent to the callers i.e. the application project can use it like any built-in control that doesn't require you to know anything about resource dictionary?

I've read about creating a new custom control project can do the trick, but it's only one control for which I don't want to create a new project for. Anyone knows how to do it in an existing class library DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5639164/986080) helped me find the trick.

1. Create a file called `Themes\Generic.xaml` to merge the resource dictionary.
2. Add the following attribute to `Assembly.cs`

   [assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]